# Knapsack Solution using Recursion and Array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I would like to know the best possible way to modify this code. Instead of adding  the integers to an array in the code itself, I would like the user to input the different weights and the capacity via keyboard.

Now I am currently having compiling errors when inserting the data. I believe the problem lies within the for loop.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NN01276494 {
  public static ArrayList <Double> sack = new ArrayList <Double> ();
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
int i =0;
 for(i = 0; i<sack.length; i++){
 System.out.println("Enter Capacity");
 sack.size(in.nextDouble());
 }
while (in.hasNextDouble()){
System.out.print("Enter weights");
sack.add(in.nextDouble());
    i++;
}


}

public static Boolean knapsackproblem(double targetWeight, int index)
{
    Boolean complete = false;

    if(index == sack.size()) return false;
    if(sack.get(index) == targetWeight)
    {
        System.out.print("Answer: " + sack.get(index) + " ");
        complete = true;
    }; //DONE
    if(sack.get(index) < targetWeight) 
    {
        complete = knapsackproblem(targetWeight-sack.get(index), index+1);         
        if(complete) System.out.print(sack.get(index) + " ");
        for(int i = index+1; i < sack.size(); i++) 
        {
            if(!complete) complete = knapsackproblem(targetWeight, i);
        }
    }
    if(sack.get(index) > targetWeight) complete =   
    knapsackproblem(targetWeight, index+1);


    return complete;
}
}
```

Comment: Better suited to [codereview.se]?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to accept user input in java is the Scanner class. This allows your users to input into the console, and your program to use their input. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html?is-external=true) is the javadoc that details scanners in detail, but here's all you need to do to accept integer inputs from your users:

First, import the scanner dictionary so you can use it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

This will give you access to the Scanner library. To construct the scanner, you need to specify an input stream in the declaration. To make the console this input stream, declare it like so:

```
Scanner nameOfScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Now, to get the integers for the array, use the method `.nextInt()` as many times as you want. Make sure to ask the user separately for each input, and if you want the user to be able to control the size of the array, you can also ask the user for that. Just in case you don't know, you can declare an array to have a certain size, but not specify what is going to be in each location until later like so:

```
int[] nameOfArray = new int[sizeOfArray];
```

On a separate note, I noticed that you had a semicolon after the closing bracket of your if statement in the middle of the `knapsackproblem()` method. I don't know if that's a typo in your question or actually in your code, but it really shouldn't be there.

I hope this helps, and good luck coding!

Comment: The extra semicolon is at the end of an if block, not a for loop.  It's unnecessary and should be removed just on general principles, but it won't cause any actual compile-time or runtime problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code so user can input the array via an ArrayList :-using ArrayList user can input data without regard to length just enter as many values as you want then at the end type any letter for ex:[Out] then your method should start working :).

```
import java.util.*;


public class knapsack {

public static void main(String [] args){

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter Capacity");
int y = in.nextInt();
double [] sack = new double [y];
System.out.println("enter values");

for (int i =0;i<y;i++){
sack[i]=in.nextDouble();
}


}

public static Boolean knapsackproblem(double targetWeight, int index ,
     double [] sack)
{
    Boolean complete = false;

    if(index == sack.length) return false;
    if(sack[index] == targetWeight)
    {
        System.out.print("Answer: " + sack[index] + " ");
        complete = true;
    }; //DONE
    if(sack[index] < targetWeight) 
    {
        complete = knapsackproblem(targetWeight-sack[index], index+1,sack);
 //keep going
        if(complete) System.out.print(sack[index] + " ");
        for(int i = index+1; i < sack.length; i++) 
        {
            if(!complete) complete = knapsackproblem(targetWeight, i,sack);
        }
    }
    if(sack[index] > targetWeight) complete = knapsackproblem(targetWeight,
index+1,sack);


    return complete;
}



}
```

Hope it helps.Also I've fixed your recursion since you wrote knapsack( instead of knapsackproblem(.ArrayList comes from java,util package which also includes the Scanner class I just got them all using * ArrayList is a class that has its own methods like .size() and .add().

Comment: I am having trouble with inputting the integers, it appears to be continuous with not end point. How would I create a set amount of integers, for example 5 integers(3,10,4,6,2). The capacity could be 25(Random Number). Would I call the `in.nextDouble` function 5 times or will I need a for loop?

Comment: As I said after you have inputted the numbers you need in the array type any letter for ex : [end ]or [false] then hit enter  ,the loop will break and your method will work .you don't need to set length in ArrayList,

Comment: if you want to set array length just get it from user via 'in.nextDouble'  insert it in the array length then use for-loop to insert values into the array..'for(int i =0;i<sack.length;i++){ sack[i] = in.nextDouble; }'

Comment: Is it something like this?                                                                           `public static ArrayList <Double> sack = new ArrayList <Double> ();
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

 for(i = 0; i<sack.length; i++){
 System.out.println("Enter Capacity");
 sack.size(in.nextDouble());
 }
while (in.hasNextDouble()){
System.out.print("Enter weights");
sack.add(in.nextDouble());
    i++;
}`

Comment: You don't need ArrayList then I've modified your code again so you can just use a regular double [] array which is inserted in your method's parameter.